# Google cloud: Expiration of Bearer token

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using a [Bearer token](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-identity-token) to access a website. I am adding this token to `Authorization HTTP-header` and I can get access to development website. It is necessary for safety. I was surprised, that Bearer token is expiring in 1 hour by default. Is it any way to fix it and change token's lifetime?

UPD: I have already known, that no, it isn't possible. There was some way to up it to 12 hours. I didn't try it, but i would like get better option.

I tried another option: Identity-Aware Proxy — not my option, it works only for GAE or HTTPS Load Balancer. I work with CloudRun without HTTPS Load Balancer.

Comment: You may be looking for Google [Session Control](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#dealing-with-session-control-policies-for-google-cloud-platform-gcp-organizations)

Comment: Please share more details what exactly you want to achieve? You want to authenticate in code, using GET request? You want to use SA, something like [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth)?

Comment: Did you have a look here? You can set up to 12h: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials

Comment: updated information

Comment: As was written above, there is way to use Oauth2.0 token form 12 hours [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-oauth). This is still not enough for your scenario? How long you would like to have this token?

Comment: @PjoterS I would like to have non-expiring access token for my developers. It isn't a comfortable option to get a new token each 12h.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite an open question as many things depend on various variables. You are using GCP IAM, ApiGee or something else.

In general as `guillaume blaquiere` mentioned in comments, you can create `Service Account` which `Access Token` will be valid for 12 hours. It's well described in the GCP IAM Doc[Creating short-lived service account credentials - Generating an OAuth 2.0 access token](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-oauth):

> By default, OAuth 2.0 access tokens are valid for a maximum of 1 hour (3,600 seconds). However, you can extend the maximum lifetime for these tokens to 12 hours (43,200 seconds).

Due to security reasons, using Non-expiring access tokens is not the best approach. Recommended way is to use `access token` and `refresh token`.

GCP also provides a product called [ApiGee](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/get-started/what-apigee). In ApiGee documentation, you can find some examples of best practice like [Secure an API with OAuth](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/tutorials/secure-calls-your-api-through-oauth-20-client-credentials?hl=en) and less secure [AntiPatterns](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/antipatterns/oauth-long-expiration), which shows example to use 30 mins `access token` and `refresh token` which will be valid for 200 days.

```
<OAuthV2 name="GenerateAccessToken">
    <Operation>GenerateAccessToken</Operation>
    <ExpiresIn>1800000</ExpiresIn> <!-- 30 minutes -->
    <RefreshTokenExpiresIn>17280000000</RefreshTokenExpiresIn> <!-- 200 days -->
    <SupportedGrantTypes>
      <GrantType>password</GrantType>
    </SupportedGrantTypes>
    <GenerateResponse enabled="true"/>
</OAuthV2>
```

More details about this method you can find in [Requesting access tokens and authorization codes - Authorization](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/security/oauth/access-tokens?hl=en) documentation.

**To sum up.**

In GCP you can extend the default validation of `access token` from 1 hour to 12 hours, not more due to security reasons. Further extension of this time you can achieve by using `refresh token`.

**Useful links:**

- [Understanding OAuth2 and deploying a basic authorization service to Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/understanding-oauth2-and-deploy-a-basic-auth-srv-to-cloud-functions?hl=en)
- [What Are Refresh Tokens and How to Use Them Securely](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/)
- [Understanding Refresh Tokens](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/)
- [Identity Platform - Using the REST API](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api?hl=en)
- [Generating access tokens](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/reference/policies/oauthv2-policy?hl=en#generateaccesstoken)

Comment: I am using GCP IAM. It isn't the best way, but it seems I should read about refresh tokens. Thank you for your answer, it isn't solving my problem, but it is helpful.